# GridSearchCV and Google colab: n_jobs=-1 does not work

Tags: python, parallel-processing, google-colaboratory, gridsearchcv

The problem is the following: when running these lines of code

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, y)
```

on **Google Colab**, it returns the error

```
PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

However, if I set `n_jobs = 1`, it perfectly works.

How can I use multiple processors on Google Colab?

Comment: Could you please provide your complete code? Have you used any other numbers for example ```n_jobs=2``` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are some possible problems for your issue:

- One problem may be your `param_grid=param_grid`, sometimes a change of grid search parameters solve the issue.
- Another potential issue may be with your model and the parameters that are used there. See this issue as an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705190/gridsearchcv-cant-pickle-function-error-when-trying-to-pass-lambda-in-paramete/50705399).
- You can try any other numbers for example `n_jobs=4` instead of `n_jobs=-1`. Also, you can use:

```
n_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

to get the number of CPUs and then

```
n_jobs=n_cpus
```

or

```
n_jobs=n_cpus - 1
```